# Where is my mistake on Qt Signal&Slot Problem?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to learn Qt. I was on signal&slot methods. I couldn't do that. As you can see I have pressed but Label text didn't change. Where is my mistake?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh2Ju.png)

Comment: paste the code instead screeshots

Comment: ypu are  mixing slots and lambdas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a lambda or define a slot:

```
connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), ui->label, SLOT(yourOwnSlot));

or lambda

connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){ui->label->setText("blabla");});
```